# How to document NSNotifications properly with headerdoc?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, documentation, nsnotification, headerdoc

The documentation for [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) contains a section *Notification* where all related [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s are listed.

Unfortunately, the header files available in Xcode don't contain the corresponding comments.

The [HeaderDoc User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001215-CH346-CHDJFEGF) shows how the `@group` tag can be used to group items together, explaining a result similar to the [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

> Grouping tags allow you to organize functions, methods, and variables into collections. In HTML output mode, the table of contents (left column) is organized into these groups. Also, the body content (right side) contains a documentation for each group. That documentation block contains the group’s name, discussion, and a list of any functions, data types, or variables contained within that group, along with their abstracts.

However, when I try using the `@group` tag, I receive a warning `Unknown command tag name`, and the `@group` tag is not highlighted in dark green, making it seem to not be recognized by Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The warning was only temporary, because the notifications themselves have not yet been documented. As soon as I started documenting the notifications, the warning disappeared.

However, Xcode still doesn't show the `group` tag in dark green like the other headerdoc tags.